# Disabling radio button after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I need some help please
 This is the html

```
<div>
<p>match1</p>
teamA <input type="radio" name="match1" onclick="update('ab');" />
teamB <input type="radio" name="match1" onclick="update('ba');" />
<p>match2</p>
teamC <input type="radio" name="match1" onclick="update('ad');" />
teamD <input type="radio" name="match1" onclick="update('dc');" />
</div>


<script>
update(results){.................}
</script>
```

I have this html so what I want I to know is 
How can I disable the radio button once the user clicks on it 
because the **update() function** changes the values when user clicks on radio button 
if he keeps clicking like that then values change each time he clicks 
or if he clicks on sibling radio button 
so please can anyone tell me how to disable radio button
 
once user clicks on it 
like for instance in match1 
if user selects teamA radio button then i want to disable both teamA and teamB radio buttons 
 
same for match2 if he clicks then disable the clciked radio and sibling radio aswell

Thanks for reading this can anyone help me please 
I can use plain js, jquery or libraries

Comment: @user , remove the inline click event , the code will be much cleaner

Comment: see this example http://jsfiddle.net/nhZXg/

Comment: i got it working thanks to every for taking time and answering my question love you all 
thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(":radio").click(function(){
   var radioName = $(this).attr("name"); //Get radio name
   $(":radio[name='"+radioName+"']").attr("disabled", true); //Disable all with the same name
});
```

What we're doing, is, when a user clicks a radio button, disable all radios with the same name.

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Comment: Getting the name attribute and doing another selection is kind of redundant isn't it? Why not `$(this).attr("disabled",true);`? (Or `.attr("disabled","disabled")`)

Comment: @nnn, it's not redundant, cause the second selector will return many objects (radio names are not unique)

Comment: @Edgar - you're right, sorry, I missed that the point was to disable the whole group of radios.

Answer (score 1):

jsfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/nhZXg/

code

```
$(":radio").click(function(){
  $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

this is the general way of doing it.

```
jQuery("input:radio").attr('disabled',true);
```

or

```
  jQuery("input:radio").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: No, doesn't work, it only disables current radio, not related radios as userXX asked.

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript, you can use a solution like this:

```
    document.getElementById("IDOfButtonElement").onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("IDOfButtonElement").disabled=true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
```

I suggest you to add `label` tag around your inputs. It cause when user clicks on the text radio button changes.

```
<label>teamA <input type="radio" name="match1" onclick="update('ab');" /></label>
```

Comment: where do i put that code

i already have one onclick function **update(result)**

Comment: you can include it in your onclick, but inline javascript is not recommended. If you are writing a big project don't do that :)

Comment: @user , check my fiddle example

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="update('ad', this);"




function onclick(word, element){
    $(element).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 }
```

Comment: No prob -- this is more so to disable the one that was clicked, not sure if you were looking for that single one or the entire collection, otherwise I agree with the others on doing ":radio" selectors